# Docker Volume - Unhandled exception: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I have a Docker Compose file to run ELK Stack

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elkstack

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elkstack
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elkstack
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elkstack:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

When I run this Docker Compose file with **docker-compose up**; I get this error stack.

> ERROR: for docker-elk_elasticsearch_1  Cannot create container for service elasticsearch: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))","StackTrace":"   at Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotifier.Show(ToastNotification notification)\r\n   at Docker.WPF.PromptShareDirectory.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\PromptShareDirectory.cs:line 26\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\Mounting\FileSharing.cs:line 80\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.d__4.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\Mounting\FileSharing.cs:line 47\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.HttpApi.Controllers.FilesharingController.d__2.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.HttpApi\Controllers\FilesharingController.cs:line 21\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"}

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

The issue was is that when you work with Docker Volumes in windows you need to specifically give Docker access to volume locations.
In my case; this docker-compose.yml file and volumes are located in D: drive.
[image]

You need to give permission to Docker to access this folder.

1. Go to **Docker Settings** and navigate to **Resources** tab and **File Sharing** under that tab and click on **+** button.
   [image]
2. In the **Select Folder** dialog appearing after that; select the navigate to folder and click on **Select Folder**.
   [image]
3. Click on **Apply & Restart**
   [image]

After restarting the Docker; try again with **docker-compose up**, and the issue is fixed. Yay!!!!!

Comment: Which version of docker desktop are you using please? I see only "Proxies" under the Resources tab.

Comment: These options are not available when running Docker Desktop in Windows Containers mode or with WSL2.